# i hava some troubles in understand the import_bvh.py when i use blender , thank to you good

Tags: python, properties

What is the meaning of the following code?

```
bone_rotation_matrix = (bone_rest_matrix_inv @bone_rotation_matrix @bone_rest_matrix)
```

I want to know what the bone_rotation_matrix represents? The result is different from the rotation value in transform panel.

Comment: the formula seems to be a eigen decomposition of some rotations (from euler, most likely) to the rest matrix. I guess this should provide the same rotation but from the rest pose.

Comment: Are you able to look at the documentation for Blender, bpy or Python?